# Repeat beginAnimations -- All Animations

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimageview

I'm making a simple image rotator by fading in and out 4 different images. It works great, until the end, when I want all four animations to repeat.

I've tried the repeat count, but that will only apply to that one specific animation. How do I create an entire loop?

My code is below. Thanks in advance!

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:slideshow cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];

    [UIView setAnimationDelay:3];
    imageOne.alpha = 0;
    imageTwo.alpha = 1;

    [UIView setAnimationDelay:6];
    imageTwo.alpha = 0;
    imageThree.alpha = 1;

    [UIView setAnimationDelay:9];
    imageThree.alpha = 0;
    imageFour.alpha = 1;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by putting a name to your animations so instead of `beginAnimations:nil`, you'd put `beginAnimations: @"Button Animations"` or something like that. Also, you should set the delegate of the animation to self. This can be done by adding the following line of code into your animation block:

```
 [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
```

Then you can put this whole entire animation block into a class method of it's own (in your view controller). Lets call it doAnimation. This is just for safe measure. the next thing you should do is implement this delegate function in your view controller:

```
 -(void) animationDidStop: (NSString *) animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context{

    if([animationID isEqualToString:@"Button Animation"]){
         [self doAnimation];
    }
 }
```

So pretty much this will ensure that your animations will repeat. If this method doesn't work, let me know, I didn't test it. But I think it'll work.

Comment: I did what you mentioned, and now my app crashes on build. Do I not need to include any sort of `[self animationDidStop];` in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Just FYI -- you have an extra space between `animationID` and `finished`... it should just be `animationIDfinished`. That being said, this is not being called for me.

Comment: Nevermind.. there are a few ways to do it. You are also correct.

Comment: Hi. The space between animationID and finished belongs there. animationID is the NSString that identifies your animation. You know where you put [UIView beginAnimation: @"AnimationID" context:nil]. Also, what I did wrong was that I should have put if([animationID isEqualToString:@"ButtonAnimations"]). That may be the reason why it didn't work. You don't have to call the animationDidStop at viewDidLoad, that's a delegate method that gets called. I also forgot to add to my answer that you need to put this line in your animation block: [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self]; I've edited my answer.

Comment: I apologize for giving you incomplete code. I was writing the answer very fast while doing other things. I guess that's what happens when you're not 100% focused.